# Special characters in Jenkins console log 39m, 90m

Tags: jenkins, console

We are seeing special characters in Jenkins console logs:

What we expect:

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Cypress:        9.7.0                                                                          │
  │ Browser:        Chrome 104 (headless)                                                          │
  │ Node Version:   v14.20.0 (/usr/bin/node)                                                      
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

What we see in Jenkins:

```
[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m                                                                                                 
  Running:  [90mwfo/speech-iq/configuration/synonyms/synonyms.spec.js[39m
```

Is there any configs to be twaeaked in Jenkins to get rid of the special characters?
We tried some suggestings as per [Jenkins console output has these strange characters from grunt command [31m[[39m...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146432/jenkins-console-output-has-these-strange-characters-from-grunt-command-31m39m) , buut no luck
Please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `NO_COLOR` environment variable to `1` should fix the problem in the case of Cypress. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#Colors

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is there a way to tweak Jenkins controller to filter out VT100 coloring characters?